# How can the window scale change suddenly, while the screen scale remains the same?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I switch focus to my React Native app, the window scale (found with Dimensions.get('window')) and PixelRatio sometimes change. The screen scale remains the same.

This messes up the layout of my app big time. Everything is twice as big or small. When not everything is rerendered I see a mix of different PixelRatios.

How can I solve this problem? How can the window scale be different from the screen scale in the first place and is there a way to prevent this?

Only thing in the documentation I could find about screen vs. window is the usable area.

Any help is appreciated, because I don't know where to look anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using the useWindowDimensions hook instead?